# Xcode UITextField textFieldDidEndEditing crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my application when the TextField loses focus I am checking the values as follows.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField.tag==1){
    [self CheckUser:textField.text];
} else if (textField.tag==2){
    [self CheckEmail:textField.text];
} else {

}
```

}

It is working fine, no problem in it.

But when I dismiss the Modal form and move to the ViewController, it is crashing. I am using the below code for dismissing the Modal View Controller.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If I remove the code - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField it is working perfectly without crash.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: What's the error message when it crashes?

Comment: Its not giving any error message simply goes to here #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: You are not giving to many information, It may crash because the keyboard is present when you dismiss the view Controller. Add this: [textField resingToFirstResponder]; at the end of your method (textFielddidEnd... and before calling dismissViewController.

Comment: anyway dismissModal is deprecated. Use dismissViewController

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting the UITextField delegate in the text field's header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Afterwards, release the `isfirstResponder` property of the text field. Use the code below as an example.

```
#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Search for tag: %@", self.searchField.text);

    if (textField == self.textField1)
    {
        [self.searchField1 resignFirstResponder];

        NSLog(@"TextField1: %@", self.textField1.text);
    } 
    else if (textField == self.textField2)
    {
        [self.searchField2 resignFirstResponder];

        NSLog(@"TextField2: %@", self.textField2.text);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Edit**

Also, if your view hierarchy is embedded in a UINavigation controller, dismiss the modal view being presented with:

```
// Apple's Description: Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the receiver.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will remove the top most View Controller. ^^^ **edit** ^^^

Last thing, if it's still not working, set strong references to your TextField IBOutlets and set each of their `.delegate` properties in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I am having interface like this  @interface SignupViewController : UIViewController<DropDownViewDelegate,ImagesGalleryDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Have you attached your textfields from Interface Builder to the corresponding View Controller's `.h` file?

Comment: this method also crashing :(

Comment: Check my edits. You might want to test the code on a new project. It seems that you have a lot going on inside your View Controller and it is often easier to fix a problem when trying to recreated it in a fresh/empty project

Comment: Ok I will try it in new project

Comment: Make sure to connect the IBOutlets to the ViewController's header as (strong, nonatomic). Also, take notice to the **dismiss method** edit. Good luck!